# Discord.py: Blacklist Cog.listener flagging error: TypeError: 'str' object not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a command that blacklist words but it doesn't seem to be working. Flags error `line 128, in on_message, msg = message.content() TypeError: 'str' object not callable`

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    """Deletes a messaged that contains a blacklisted word"""

    msg = message.content()

    for word in msg:

        if msg.find("blacklist") != -1:

            await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to use an attribute, `.content`, as a function. You can't call an attribute.

The correct way of getting a message's content is by just removing those brackets.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    """Deletes a messaged that contains a blacklisted word"""

    msg = message.content
    
    ...
```

Comment: It works but it flags error `discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message`

Comment: The line that `await message.delete()` is on in my example

Comment: That means that the message was already deleted. So I'd check if any other bots are deleting the messages before yours.

Comment: There is no other bots.

Comment: Oh. You're not exiting once you've found the "blacklisted" word. 
Once the message is deleted, it can't be deleted again.
So you need to put `return` or `break` under `await message.delete()`